# How to write the same code using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 }; 
string[] strings = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }; 

var textNums = 
    from n in numbers 
    select strings[n]; 

Console.WriteLine("Number strings:"); 
foreach (var s in textNums) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(s); 
}
```

How to write the same code using Lambda Expression....

Comment: I have to ask: *why* do you want to move it to a lambda expression? The current code is perfectly clear and efficient. Forcing in a lambda is... odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result=numbers.Select(n=>strings[n]);
```

This is correct but result is of type `IEnumerable< String >`.
Here,left hand-sided `n` of `=>(lambda operator)` means the parameter that is passed into a function and the right-sided `strings[n]` of `=>` means the function body.

For more on Linq & lambda expression refer to:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers.ToList().ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(strings[item]));
```

Comment: can't we write like this:var xyz=numbers.ToList().ForEach(item => (strings[item]));

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean the "from in"-statement only?:

```
var textNs = numbers.Select(i => strings[i]);
```

Comment: I think you mean `n => strings[n]`.

Comment: @hvd what is the difference between 'i' and 'n'?

Comment: That was not what was wrong; I just fetched the n'th (or i'th, if you will) number from `numbers` in stead of from `strings` by mistake at first. Changed to the correct variable now. (For the record, whatever you put in before the `=>` symbol is just a variable, like any other. It could be `Select(fishMarket => strings[fishMarket]`) if you like.

Comment: oh sorry then, didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = numbers.Select(n => strings[n]);
```

Comment: Here what will n indicates? I think it is just a user defined variable....I'm confused....